# How to convert conditions in Excel to python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hello all need help to convert Excel conditions to python pandas

```
=IF(COUNTIF(sheetname[@[Column 1]:[Column 3]],">0")>1,"Yes","No")
```

I have a excel table like this

```
|cat1 | Cat2 | Cat 3|
 0      0      1
 1      1      2
 1      1      0
 1      0      0
```

I want to achieve this in python pandas dataframe

```
|cat1 | Cat2 | Cat 3| Multiple|
 0      0      1.      No
 1      1      2.      Yes
 1      1      0.      Yes
 1      0      0       No
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check how many values in each row are greater than 0, and if the result is more than 1 a `True` will be returned (and a `False` otherwise).

```
df['Multiple'] = (df.gt(0).sum(axis=1) > 1)
```

prints:

```
   cat1  Cat2  Cat 3  Multiple
0     0     0      1     False
1     1     1      2      True
2     1     1      0      True
3     1     0      0     False
```

You can chain `.map({True:'Yes',False:'No'})` at the end of the above code which will give you exactly what you are after:

```
   cat1  Cat2  Cat 3 Multiple
0     0     0      1       No
1     1     1      2      Yes
2     1     1      0      Yes
3     1     0      0       No
```

You will need to make sure that your 'Cat' columns are of a numeric type.

Comment: Could you also account for the selection of columns ( the `[Column 1]:[Column 3]` part of the excel code)? Maybe `df.iloc[:, 0:2]....` or `df[['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']]....`?

Comment: @NithinRamayanam please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem, so other people with a similar issue can find it easier.

Comment: this worked df.loc[:, "cat_1":"cat_3"]

Comment: In the left side there should be a couple of arrows and a tick. Just mark the tick. Look at the pictures [in the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: # i am not able to mark. i dont know why